# Do detection of Kidney cysts (PKD) at an early stage helps prevention of Kidney Failure?

Tags: kidney-disease, cysts

Kidney cysts are becoming 4th leading factor of kidney failure unfortunately. **There is no cure of PKD yet** though research is going on! 
My question is "If a person suffers from PKD detects it accidently at very early age suppose at his twenties. Will it be helpful to him anyway as there is no cure available? At early stage, there are only some cysts on Kidney then at later stage where thousands of cysts reside on Kidney stopping Kidney to do its functionality.

Also I found:

> Q. Does everyone with PKD develop kidney failure? 
>  
> Answer: About 50 percent of people with PKD will have kidney failure by age 60, and about 60 percent will have kidney failure by age 70. People with kidney failure will need dialysis or a kidney transplant.
> Source: [Kidney.org](https://www.kidney.org/atoz/content/polycystic)

Comment: Leading factor?  Reference for this claim?  I see that 5% of renal failure is attributed to polycystic kidney disease.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Updated and added source for reference.

Answer (score 3):

There is [no way](https://www.kidney.org/blog/kidney-cars/pkd-preventable) to prevent PKD. However, there is [a drug](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/02/170216103905.htm) in pre-clinical trials now that may be effective in treatment of PKD.

> Researchers at UT Southwestern Medical Center, working with a
>   California biotech firm, have developed a potential drug to treat
>   polycystic kidney disease -- an incurable genetic disease that often
>   leads to end-stage kidney failure.
>
> The drug, now called RGLS4326, is in preclinical animal testing at San
>   Diego-based Regulus Therapeutics Inc. An investigational new drug
>   filing to pave the way for human clinical trials is expected later
>   this year, said Dr. Vishal Patel, Assistant Professor of Internal
>   Medicine at UT Southwestern.

Comment: @ZahidKhan No, it's only in animal testing at this point. It will be several years before it becomes available to patients, and that's not guaranteed to happen. Many drugs that seem promising initially never make it to market.

Comment: What makes it so hard to diagnose PKD? There are almost cure for every disease in 21st Century. I also heard that BioTech Kidney(Artificial) kidneys is on the way for PKD patients who are on verge of kidney failure, how true is that?

Comment: @ZahidKhan These should be new questions

Comment: There are a great many diseases with no cure and no cure on the horizon here in the 21st century. It's actually quite a long list. I agree with @Narusan that you need to make these things new questions.